# focus-in-event fires even when entry is not focused

Tags: python, events, gtk, pygtk

I am creating a gtk.Entry, and want to hook into its "focus in" event, so I can pop up a virtual keyboard:

```
class LabelEntry(gtk.HBox):
    # ... initialization ...

    self.keyboard = virtualkeyboard.VirtualKeyboard()
    self.entry = gtk.Entry()
    self.entry.connect('focus-in-event', self.keyboard.focus_handler)

    # ... attach the gtk.Entry to this gtk.HBox, etc. ...
```

This correctly opens the `focus_handler` callback contained within the `VirtualKeyboard` class, and a new window is displayed over the top of the current one.

Once the virtual keyboard window is dismissed, I see the original window with the updated value for that `self.entry`. However, if I tap *anywhere* on the original window (not even on the gtk.Entry, the same callback is fired and the virtual keyboard is displayed again.

What would cause a touch anywhere on the original window to register as a "focus in" event for the gtk.Entry? Do I need to blur the focus when I open the new window, or create a flag that indicates that I've already opened the window and shouldn't open it again?

**EDIT**

This comes from a [modified version](http://pastebin.com/tyHAnQ1w) of [wicd 1.7](https://launchpad.net/wicd/1.7)'s `guiutil.py` file, plus a new Virtual Keyboard ([python file](http://pastebin.com/t1DWyp7u), [glade file](http://pastebin.com/3xYzLv8f)) that should open whenever an Entry is selected.

I'm trying to avoid an arduous "has this been clicked before? Did you just lose focus? Did you just get focus again, but you had been clicked before and need to ignore THIS focus event?" logic puzzle.

Comment: are you using `pygtk` or `girepository`? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I'm using `pygtk`. It's actually a modified version of the `wicd` gtk UI. I added a few pastebin files with the sources.

Answer (score 0):

> The ::focus-in-event signal will be emitted when the **keyboard focus
>   enters the widget 's window**.
>
> To receive this signal, the GdkWindow associated to the widget needs
>   to enable the GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK mask.

So this is desired behavour.

To get what you want, you could just check if the desired widget actually has the focus via `gtk_widget_is_focus(...)` (this is different from `gtk_widget_has_focus(...)` - RTM for details).